# Switch from share to singleton function with custom mail driver

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Right now I try to upgrade my application from Laravel 5.3 to 5.4. Everything worked fine except for my custom mail driver for Mailjet.

I set a custom MailServiceProvider to register the Mailjet Driver. Right now it looks links this (and worked fine with 5.3):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class MailServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider
{
    public function registerSwiftTransport()
    {
        $this->app['swift.transport'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) {
            return new \App\Mail\Transport\TransportManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

In Laravel 5.4 is the share-function no longer supported. It is recommended to use singleton(). So I tried a serveral things. I think with the following code I got very near to a working solution:

```
public function registerSwiftTransport()
{
     $this->app->singleton('swift.transport', function ($app) {
        return new \App\Mail\Transport\TransportManager($app);
    });
}
```

But here I get a 500 error because the HandleExceptions.php is running out of space.

I also tried to move my custom TransportManager.php file to \App\Providers\ and changed the return line like this:

```
return new \App\Providers\TransportManager($app);
```

Here it says "Class 'App\Providers\TransportManager' not found". But: Yes, the file is in the right directory.

Any ideas how to solve my problem with the missing share-function in some simple steps or do you think I have to overthink my whole maildriver installation.

Thanks

Comment: What is the namespace of your transport provider?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to set it to App\Providers after moving the file. But when I change it this way I also get the 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is something wrong inside your `TransportManager` class, it looks like your current code should work. However, there is a more correct way to implement a new mail driver, and it completely avoids the issue you're having.

The `\Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager` class extends the `\Illuminate\Support\Manager` class. This means that the class has an `extend()` method to allow you to add in your own custom drivers, without having to attempt to override the entire manager in the first place.

So, instead of your current solution, either in your AppServiceProvider, or a new service provider, you should be looking for something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class MailjetServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app['swift.transport']->extend('mailjet', function($app) {
            // your logic for building $transport

            return $transport;
        });
    }
}
```

That service provider will allow you to use the `mailjet` mail driver, and it will call that closure to resolve the driver.